# Search Symbol change within Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, address, search, icon

This is to be used on a public website so usability is key. When searching an address the small dot symbol appears. Is it possible to change this symbol to a different icon such as a square or house to ensure it is clear for members of the public to see?
This is created in Web App Builder within ArcGIS online

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Developer edition, or WAB from within ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I am using WAB within ArcGIS online